# Tensorflow: Quantize graph not working

Tags: terminal, tensorflow, bazel

I've been following this tutorial to quantize the graph for iOS: https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/

I run this in in terminal:

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/quantization:quantize_graph && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph \
--input=stripped_graph.pb \
--input_node_names=Mul \
--output_node_names=final_result \
--output=final_output_graph.pb \
--mode=eightbit
```

However, all it outputs is the following:

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/tools/quantization:quantize_graph up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.748s, Critical Path: 0.30s
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

Why isn't it completing the command? Does my computer require a GPU?

**Update**

Running the same command in a docker image outputs the following:

```
ERROR: /tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:1315:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:matrix_solve_ls_op' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -Wl,-z,-relro,-z,now -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-canonical-system-headers ... (remaining 100 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 4.
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

**Update**

For anyone who encounters this, just run the command to quantize your graph in terminal without using docker, it may take a while (Mine took about an hour) but it should work and it doesn't require GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it just took an hour to output and wasn't updating.